# Powershell select-string Matching x AND y

Tags: powershell, select-string

I'm trying to do a search of some log files for lines that contain certain strings. The files contain multiple lines like:

```
ALARM  11/08/2014 10:00:02,InFILE typeID,actionID,customerID: various_other_data_here

ALARM  11/08/2014 10:00:03,OutFILE typeID,actionID,customerID: various_other_data_here
```

I'm trying to find all lines in all files that have both 'ALARM' and 'OutFILE' in them.

I can use:

```
select-string .\*.log -pattern "ALARM"
```

to find all instances of 'ALARM', but how can I add the additional 'OutFILE'. 
I've searched for this and found loads of examples that seem to be aimed at matching really copmplex strings with long ReEx, but nothing that is for matching simple x AND y type strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple regex to match your scenario. This should work:

`select-string .\*.log -pattern 'ALARM.*outFile'`

Comment: cheers. I had 'ALARM*outfile', but was missing the dot. So obvious when someone else points it out. Cheers again.